# Sass - H5 text alignment

Tags: sass, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Hi i am currently working with rails 4.2 and using sass , and haml .   I am trying to center align the h5 that i have but it seems that it doesnt want to cooperate with me and i already tried with the search with google but still a fail

this is my code

the static page is this

```
.row#mod
    .container#space
        .row
            .col-md-2
                .thumbnail
                    .caption
                        =image_tag "a.png", tag: "",class: "img-thumbnail"
                        %h5
                            %b#tag Lead
                        %br
```

The sass is this

```
#tag
    text-align: center
```

but the center alignment of the h5 is still to no avail can anybody help me and thanks

Comment: This is not a Rails or Sass problem, provide the compiled markup/CSS.

Comment: Is this to style just the one h5 tag on the page, other wise make the styling more generalised to something like '.thumbnail .caption h5' and add 'text-align: center' to that.

Answer (score 0):

The id `tag` is on the inline element `<b>`, so `text-align: center` won't center it within the block h5 element.  You can either make #tag `display: block`, or you should move `text-align: center` to the h5.

### Example 1:

```
#tag
    display: block
    text-align: center
```

### Example 2:

```
.caption h5
    text-align: center
```